# How do I check if the same tag was already in database with PHP and Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want this script to check to see if the same word has been entered if so it should add it to the count not add a duplicate tag.

And if the tag entered is a new tag then let it add it to the database.

Can some one help me fix this?

```
$tag = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tag']);
$query = "INSERT INTO tags (tag, count) VALUES ('$tag', 1)
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count+1";
if (!mysql_query($query, $dbc))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($dbc)
```

THANKS EVERYONE I GOT IT TO WORK BUT ANOTHER PROBLEM CAME UP BUT IT'S A DIFFERENT QUESTION

Comment: What error are you getting? What does your table look like? What else have you tried?

Comment: here is how my table basically looks like: id  tag  count

Comment: the table adds a duplicat entry instead of adding it to the count.

Comment: your code would only work if tag was the primary key on the table, is this the case?

Comment: Was there one answer that pushed you over the finish line?

Answer (score 3):

try this query to add a primary key to your tags table

```
ALTER TABLE tags  ADD PRIMARY KEY (tag);
```

**UPDATE**

Just run it in phpmyadmin OR

do this

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE tags  ADD PRIMARY KEY (tag)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

in a test.php

**UPDATE 2**

OK this means you already have a primary key, you can add a unique index to tag now using this query ..

ALTER TABLE tags ADD UNIQUE (tag);

Please note that if you already have duplicates, then you'll need to remove them first.

Comment: it tells me Multiple primary key defined?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it is easy. Add unique index on 'tag' column in database or make it primary key.

Comment: You would do this in whatever tool you are using to manage your database, for example the MySQL command tool http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/mysql.html or phpMyAdmin http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the id will probably be the primary key, not tag. as i mentioned above your code would only work if tag was the primary key on the table

Answer (score 0):

You say that the structure of your table is as follows:

```
id    tag    count
```

Which means your current query won't work unless you have `tag` as the primary key. If that's the case, you're probably using the `id` column as the primary key.

So take it easy and just check to see if the tag is already there.

If so, update the count. If not, add it.

```
//--grab the tag
$tag = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tag']);

//--see if the tag already exists and potentially what the current count is
$query = "SELECT id, count FROM tags WHERE tag='$tag'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

//--if there is a row, that means the tag exists
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
//--pull out the tag ID and the current count and increment by one.
  $tag_info = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $tag_info_id = $tag_info["id"];
  $tag_info_count = $tag_info["count"] + 1;

//--update the table with the new count
  $sql_update_cnt = "UPDATE tags SET count='$tag_info_count' 
                            WHERE id='$tag_info_id'";
  mysql_query($sql_update_cnt);

  echo "$tag now with $tag_info_count instances";
}
else
{
//--tag is not there, so insert a new instance and 1 as the first count
  $query = "INSERT INTO tags (tag, count) VALUES ('$tag', 1)";
  mysql_query($query);

  echo "1 record added";
}

mysql_close($dbc);
```

Comment: I'm trying your solution this is how my database is set up:

<pre>
CREATE TABLE tags (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
tag varchar(100) NOT NULL,
count int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
);

</pre>

for some reason now my databse wont update now:(

Comment: Fixed up the error where the query to create a new tag was left out. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

if you’re using mySQL, you can use the `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax, provided your tagname is the primary key (or unique)

```
INSERT INTO `tags` (`tag`, `count`)
VALUES ($tag, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `count`=`count`+1;
```

to add a primary key on your table use:

```
ALTER TABLE `tags` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tag`)
```

you don’t need an `id` column though, because you can use your tagname as primary key

```
ALTER TABLE `tags` DROP COLUMN `id`
```